# How to add 2 Mat pixel values while iterating through pixels using OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, colors

I have 2 Mat, both have same size. Then I split those 2 Mat to process the BGR value of each Mat (in my case, it's actually BGRA). Then I want to add each of BGR values from those 2 Mat and store it in `blue, green, red` variable.

I successfully adding 2 Mat without using pixel iteration, like this :

```
//below operation works
blue = img1_split1[0] + img2_split[0];
green = img1_split[1] + img2_split[1];
red = img1_split[2] + img2_split[2];
```

But I'm facing Exception Unhandled if I use pixel iteration and add 2 pixel values from each Mat, like this :

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF89AA69129 in VideoStitcher.exe:
>   Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location
>   0x000000ADA5CFD020.

Here's my code :

```
Mat img1, img2;
img1 = imread("some_image.jpg");  //this is just for example
img2 = imread("some_image.jpg");

vector<Mat> img1_split, img2_split;

split(img1, img1_split);
split(img2, img2_split);

Mat blue, green, red;

    for (int i = 0; i < img1.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < img1.cols; j++)
        { //below operation doesn't work
            blue.at<uchar>(i, j) = img1_split1[0].at<uchar>(i, j) + img2_split[0].at<uchar>(i, j);
            green.at<uchar>(i, j) = img1_split[1].at<uchar>(i, j) + img2_split[1].at<uchar>(i, j);
            red.at<uchar>(i, j) = img1_split[2].at<uchar>(i, j) + img2_split[2].at<uchar>(i, j);
        }
    }
```

Can somebody point out the mistake that I made? Thanks

Comment: as it is in the code provided, you have  not initialized non of the cv::Mat. I guess img1 and img2 are initialized in your code, but is blue, green and red initialized?

Comment: @api55 img1 and img2 is initialized (imread real image). While blue, green and red is written exactly like example above. Do I have to initialize them with all 0 or something?

Comment: yep, just try `Mat blue(img1.rows, img1.cols, img1.type), green(img1.rows, img1.cols, img1.type), red((img1.rows, img1.cols, img1.type)`

Comment: @api55 it gives 2 errors : 
`Error C2664 'cv::Mat::Mat(cv::Mat &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'cv::Size'` and `Error C3867 'cv::Mat::type': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member`

Comment: Sorry, I did it from memory, it is `img1.type()` mind the parenthesis. I will write it as answer :) with more explanations

Comment: @api55 i changed to `.type()`, now it is compiled but still produces same exception as before

Comment: what are the sizes of img2 and blue, green, red? (i.e. img2.size)

Comment: @api55 the size of img1 and img2 are `[960 x 540] [960 x 540]` , blue, green and red should follow their size right?

Comment: @api55 Shouldn't red,green and blue be of type `CV_8UC1` since they each represent a single channel of the input images?

Comment: @zindarod true, I miss that, however I tried it in my pc and I do not get anerror, I get one third of the image due to CV_8UC1 vs CV_8UC3

Comment: @gameon67 I tested my answer with OpenCV 3.4, and I get no error. Are you sure it does not work?

Comment: The most glaring mistake are those nested loops instead of just using a matrix expression (e.g. `blue = img1_split + img2_split`) -- which would avoid accessing the unitialized `Mat`, avoid the overflow in your calculation, need less code and most likely perform better. In fact, I'd even say do `img1 + img2` and only split the result that if you need the channels separate.

Comment: @DanMašek normally I would prefer without the loop, but I need to perform calculation on each pixel. e.g. if this pixel result this value then do this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cv::Mat works like a shared smart pointer, so when one creates it  with the default constructor (i.e. `cv::Mat x;`), it does not have any data or type and its `.data` member points nowhere.

You need to pass at least rows and cols and type for it to be able to allocate the image data, for example, in your case it will be like:

```
Mat blue(img1.rows, img1.cols, CV_8UC1), green(img1.rows, img1.cols, CV_8UC1), red(img1.rows, img1.cols, CV_8UC1);
```

I used `CV_8UC1`, since they are one channel images once you split them.

When you set pixels like this, you have to be careful with underflow and overflow... there is a nice function for that, it is call [saturate_cast](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#gab93126370b85fda2c8bfaf8c811faeaf).

Comment: sorry for late response. It works after change the type to `CV_8UC1`. Thanks for the extra explanation

Comment: 1 edit, it should be `green(img1.rows, img1.cols, CV_8UC1)`